# Moving Row inside a Table View with tap - Swift

Tags: sorting, swift, tableview, cell

I'm try to simulate the dragging of the cell with the single tap on the cell.

Once tapped the single cell has to be the first item in the list. 
I tried with ll the method but my indexpath change but I don't see the result in the table, even if i reload it.

Any Suggestion?

here's my code:

```
import UIKit

var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

class Table: UITableViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

            tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel.text = array[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}

    var indexPathForCell = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPathForCell: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.reloadData()
    println(indexPathForCell)

//        

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath indexPathForCell: NSIndexPath) {
    println(indexPathForCell)
}

}
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want any cell you tap to move to the top of the list?

Comment: Yes! Exactly this, but with the animation as well. Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To swap a cell's position animated, you'll need to update your data source and the tableView's representation at the same time. You can do that like this:

```
table.beginUpdates()

table.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0))
array.insert(array.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row), atIndex: 0)

table.endUpdates()
```